# Android TCP TLS 1.2 connection works fine than stops working at all

Tags: android, iis, tls1.2

My app has had a very stable tcp sender/receiver and I managed to also get tcp + tls 1.2 working in the same send/receive service. **It works for some hours and then just completely stops working.** All while the app also uses a soap connection over https using ksoap2 with same url and certificate. I can see in DB that soap worked long after tcp messages stopped.

I have update a long running gpsgate tracking app to be able to use tls also.
The app used to have tcp connection only and has gotten very robust over the years:
Connection-Service will be rebound by a control service, it also has a Thread that starts reconnecting if no messages have come in for some minues.
Socket works just fine for hours. It sends a kind of heartbeat 1x per minute if no other messages are present to keep the connection established so the server can actively send something to the mobile not only respond.

The only thing I change if ssl port is configured is I make an SslSocket instead of normal tcp socket. Listener and sender code are the same just using a different type of Socket.
Only socket creation code is different for unsecure tcp and tcp+tls.

On first connect I check cert url and expiration. On a reconnect cert is not available but that seems to be a known java8 error. I changed it so it will still accept without cert if the session is valid. (I use only perfect forward security ciphers).

The server side is windows server 2012 (so no tls 1.3 support I guess) and IIS. Cert is also used for browser when administrating or using the gpsgate server. It is a well known authority no self-cert.

Server did log a lot of erros when I struggled with getting it to work (not finding cert). But this error is not logged at all (maybe server is not even getting anything).

At the moment I do not have logcat for the connectionservice as we reverted to normal tcp and I am working on something else atm.

**Any thoughts on how / why the tls 1.2 might work for some hours and then stops working while the certificate is still actively working?**

Comment: Check if TLS sessions are updated regularly. For security reasons, some systems may have session timeouts. If the session is not updated, it may expire, causing the connection to be lost.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose this issue without detailed logs or specific error messages. It is recommended that you obtain detailed logs from both the client and server sides. Check for information such as the establishment of a TLS connection, any errors encountered, and the status of the connection over time.